# Does DAO pattern defeat the purpose of Connection pool

Tags: spring, connection, singleton, dao, pool

If I have 5 entities and 5 corresponding DAOs auto-wired in service layer. Wouldn't it mean that my application will be using only 5 DB connections at any point of time.. Regardless of how many DB connections my application server can support efficiently?
Or am I missing on some thing here?

Comment: Probably not, even though it's possible to wire it up like that. You usually have a session for a request, not for a DAO.

Comment: sorry! Not quite followed. If a DAO is singleton, it will be using only one DB connection.

Comment: That's not true generally for DAO, DAO is an abstract pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object. Maybe for your specific library, which you do not mention. Anyway, I don't see a use case where single connection per DAO is useful. I guess you are wrong.

Comment: I think I got the point here. Generally every CRUD method in DAO will create a new connection and close/return in to pool. So despite of being a singleton various threads can still access the DAO simultaneously meaning creating as many connections as supported by resource manager.